# rolling back a set of changes made from a certain date/time

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, restore

We are trying to install an application on Ubuntu and RHEL, which requires a number of steps, for e.g. install Tomcat, deploy war files, make changes to routes, change configuration files etc. Often, a single mistake messes up the installation.

Is there a preferred method which allows rolling back all the changes and restore the machine to a previous state, i.e. reverse the edits made - say from a specific date and time?

Thanks

Comment: Is the machine a VM with snapshot capabilities?

Comment: Snapshots are difficult in our case - a different department administers VSphere, so any VM restore is a ticket that can take up to a day (sometimes longer).  VM snapshot itself is yet another ticket :-(

Comment: Why aren't you scripting the process or creating puppet manifests for it?

Comment: That would be a different question for execs, on a different (corporatecontrols.stackexchange?) forum! However, going back to the original question - does such a utility exist, to roll back a set of commands, moves and edits done to the machine - so it can be rolled back to its earlier state, other than relying on VMWare snapshots etc.?

Comment: The short answer is "no" - the shell is not a time machine.  If, for example, one of the commands you wanted to "roll back" was `rm /path/to/something`, your recourse would be to recover from a backup.  This sort of question is what snapshots and backups are _for_.  _However_, if you know the state you want the system to be _in_, you could use (e. g.) Ansible to reliably reset the state of the facets of the host which are relevent to your use-case.

Comment: try cloning the VM in a dev/testing environment (NOTE: must not have write access to "live" / production data, and preferably not even read...should use only a copy/sample of test data), upgrading it, testing that everything works, and then push it to the production environment if there are no problems.

Comment: Has anyone tried Ansistrano - if this is suitable in this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can list packages with the install dates and then write a different script to remove them all. Best of luck

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```